# yii2 project running errors

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

I am installed yii2 advanced template using composer all are working fine.
System  have php7.1.5. Whenever i copy advanced folder in another system it throw syntax error in TestCase.php like below

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in \advanced\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php on line 822

```
line 822 is $configurationFilePath = $GLOBALS['__PHPUNIT_CONFIGURATION_FILE'] ?? '';
```

That another system have php5.6.8
So, i am directly install yii2 advanced in that system and it is working fine.
I am check TestCase.php the file have lot of differences and the particular line also changed like below

```
$configurationFilePath = (isset($GLOBALS['__PHPUNIT_CONFIGURATION_FILE']) ? $GLOBALS['__PHPUNIT_CONFIGURATION_FILE'] : '');
```

So i want to know what is going here.My question is not clear please let me know.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP operator `??` is available since PHP7, so u can't expect, that code from PHP7 will work on server with PHP5.

[PHP 7 - Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: thank you.So Yii2 installed automatically based on php version